# why do i always get this error whenever i use forge init?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, foundry, forge

[image: using forge init always throws this error]

I am trying to use foundry, whenever i use forge init on my mac it throws this error and doesn't install forge-std lib for me.
According to the error, it said i should add the --no-commit option but whenever i do so forge-std isn't installed.

please how do i resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

forge init requires that from the folder you are calling it, does not have a git folder already installed.

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks, i resolved it.

Comment: Great! @Love4codes can you check the question as answered, so other devs can see it has a solution, thks